# Moving a file with an excel macro

Tags: excel, vba

I would like my csv to be able to run a command the moves a file from location the home directory to the public directory on Windows.

I have tried various syntax's, all prefix with =cmd', which is used to execute a command.

```
=cmd|’move C:\document.docx C:\public\document.docx’!
```

This should be moving this file to the public directory, which is accessible through the web. However, I am not able to retrieve it. I am running MacOS, so I'm not able to test this locally. The target box is remote.

Comment: `CSV` can't do it. It would require macro enable workbook `.xlsm` file format.

Comment: Maybe he is talking about CSV injection although I do not know if this working on a MAC

Comment: I just tested it with a CSV file containing a line similar to _"=cmd|' /C move filename1 filename2_ and it's indeed working on a windows machine. For CSV injection you can look [here](http://georgemauer.net/2017/10/07/csv-injection.html). But the question is: Why do you want to do it like that?

Answer (score 0):

CSV is a limited in functionality excel format (only for integration between various platforms or applications programmed with other languages)
you can do this with ".xlsm or .xlsb" formats only

i found this code in another thread

```
Sub MoveFiles()
Dim sourceFolderPath As String, destinationFolderPath As String
Dim FSO As Object, sourceFolder As Object, file As Object
Dim fileName As String, sourceFilePath As String, destinationFilePath As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
sourceFolderPath = "D:\SourceFolder"
destinationFolderPath = "D:\DestinationFolder"
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set sourceFolder = FSO.Getfolder(sourceFolderPath)
For Each file In sourceFolder.Files
fileName = file.Name
If InStr(fileName, ".xlsx") Then ' Only xlsx files will be moved
    sourceFilePath = file.Path
    destinationFilePath = destinationFolderPath & "\" & fileName
    FSO.MoveFile Source:=sourceFilePath, Destination:=destinationFilePath
End If ' If InStr(sourceFileName, ".xlsx") Then' Only xlsx files will be moved
Next
'Don't need set file to nothing because it is initialized in for each loop 
'and after this loop is automatically set to Nothing
Set sourceFolder = Nothing
Set FSO = Nothing
End Sub
```

you can find a suitable answers here
"stackoverflow.com/questions/38456928/move-files-from-one-folder-to-another"

Answer (score 0):

Use `Name...AS` statement

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/name-statement

```
Sub moveFile()
    dim oldname as string, newname as string
    oldname = "C:\document.docx"
    newname = "C:\public\document.docx"

    name oldname as newname
End Sub
```